# MVVM & iOS - The Missing Rules

Tags: ios, mvvm

I've being working for a bit now with MVVM along with Swift. The principle is very simple:

1. **ViewController** *is responsible for* the **View**;
2. **ViewModel** *is responsible for* the **Model**;
3. **ViewController** *owns* the **View**;
4. **ViewController** *owns* the **ViewModel**;
5. **ViewModel** *own* the **Model**;

period.

That's clear to me. But there are some questions I still have about it (they might sound stupid, but it's important to be as clear to newbies as the rules above):

1. **Should ViewModel be responsible for the business logic?** I mean, since ViewController don't own models, it feels right to place the biz logic in ViewModel;
2. **Should ViewModel be a `struct`?** This is a tricky one. I'm guessing ViewModel should also give an API to ViewController interact with data. Therefore, sometimes we need to use some *[escaping closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546)* in order to fetch asynchronous data (e.g. HTTP calls). Structs can't hold it.
3. **Should I hide non-outlets variables from ViewController?** Sometimes we need a strong reference to some property in order to present views (e.g. keep the current page of an `UIPageControl`). Should ViewController hold this reference?
4. **How can I fire ViewController updates from ViewModel?** I do read about [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), but my question is wider: Sometimes ViewModel needs ViewController to respond to some actions, which is the best way to do it? Should ViewModel keep specific callbacks to specific reactions ViewController can handle? I came across [Srdan Rasic's post](http://rasic.info/bindings-generics-swift-and-mvvm/) about "binding" properties and I got confused (perhaps its not related to this question at all).

I'll be glad if you guys can share your solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite wide. Someone will certainly explain it more widely than me, or might have different opinions. But these are my observations:

**1.** Yes ViewModel should be the only component which handles business logic

**2.** I guess that you answered it yourself, it should be a `class`. I do not have any reason for why should it be `struct`. But if it fits your needs who am I to say.

**3.** Depends on the use. If you use it for purpose of a view, then it is okay to have it here. There also exists a concept of having separate ViewModels for smaller parts, unfortunately, do not know the name. I mean you have a main ViewModel for a whole view and subViewModels for subview. So you will not end up having a big bunch of a code in `ViewModel`. Also sometimes it is acceptable technical debt (hope that no on will kill me for saying that)

**4.** It goes like this. You will press the button, you will call the method in your `ViewModel` called `buttonPressed`(or triggers an event). Then your `ViewModel` will do its job, probably obtain a new data and sets the view for that. From what I've seen you might do it with having a weak reference to your `View` in your `ViewModel`, or bind reactive properties in your View. The second option will leave you without the need of having `View` in your `ViewModel`, but you will have to to register observer for every view setting property from `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Luzo. I liked your solution for question 4, very clever! However, in my quest for the truth, I found some discussion about the topic 2 (actually is a wider discussion about MVVM pattern, which made me write this StackOverflow question: http://matteomanferdini.com/mvvm-pattern-ios-swift/). No one seems to agree with MVVM definitions & good practices. Perhaps because there is no concrete answers from official sources.

Comment: I was used to what is described here as do not use it (at least I guess). They make view models as simple objects. They use DataViewController as the driver for change, not the view model. Anyways, in my approach, you can completely avoid any escaping closures. You can just simply bind signal for its return.